# Geospacial search returns less results than available

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection (users) with 356 documents and an index "2dsphere" on the field geodata. 120 documents have a field geodata:{type:"Point", coordinates:[X,Y]} where X and Y are coordinates within Germany.

If I execute the following aggregation:

```
db.users.aggregate(
    [
        {
            "$geoNear":{
                near: { type: "Point", coordinates: [48.783469, 9.181842] },
                distanceField: "distanceCalculated",
                spherical: true
            }
        },
        {
             "$sort":{"distanceCalculated":1}
        }
    ]
)
```

I get 46 results, but as I understand, I should get at least 100 (standard for the limit parameter)
As I can see, all results are within ~210 kilometers is there any not documented standard maxDistance? I also tried different maxDistance values but never get more than 48 results.

My question is, what do I have to do to get all (120) results ordered by distance?

Answer (score 0):

Found the pitfall:
All (120) documents had the type of geodata.coordinates set to object instead of array. Unfortunately I can't say why mongoDB nevertheless returned some results instead of null. I converted all entries using the following command, now it works:

```
db.users.find({ "geodata": { $exists: true, $ne: null }}).forEach((user)=> { 
  var coordinates = user.geodata.coordinates;
  user.geodata.coordinates = [coordinates["0"], coordinates["1"]];
  db.users.save(user);
});
```